# Why can't dash search find a program by its full name?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, search

For some applications, dash search comes up empty when searching by the application's full name. When typing the first couple of letters, it works. I wonder why...

MuseScore is a fine example. When I search for "muse" in the dash search, MuseScore is found. When I search for "musescore", nothing is found.

This behavior makes me distrustful of the dash search... I wonder how often it misses installed programs... I like to be able to trust the software tools I'm using.

Answer (score 2):

The Dash search in general could use more improvement, here's a few bugs I found with Dash search:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/752259
- and a [bunch more](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-lens-applications?field.searchtext=search&search=Search&field.status:list=NEW&field.status:list=INCOMPLETE_WITH_RESPONSE&field.status:list=INCOMPLETE_WITHOUT_RESPONSE&field.status:list=CONFIRMED&field.status:list=TRIAGED&field.status:list=INPROGRESS&field.status:list=FIXCOMMITTED&field.assignee=&field.bug_reporter=&field.omit_dupes=on&field.has_patch=&field.has_no_package=).

I recommend filing a bug on the musescore package, just in case it's an easy fix like fixing the description in the .desktop file or something.

- [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)